# Proving any linear transformation can be represented as a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that

> **Theorem.** Consider a linear transformation $T : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$.
>   The transformation $T$ can be represented as a matrix product $\mathbf x \mapsto A \mathbf x$, for some matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$.

Here's my attempt at a constructive proof.

> **Proof.** Consider a matrix $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$ given by
>   \begin{align*}
>   \mathbf x &=
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     x_1 \\
>     x_2 \\
>     \vdots \\
>     x_n
>   \end{bmatrix}.
> \end{align*}
>   We will construct a matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ such that $T(\mathbf x) = A \mathbf x$.
>
> The vector $\mathbf x$ can also be written as
>   \begin{align*}
>   \mathbf x &=
>   x_1
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     1 \\
>     0 \\
>     \vdots \\
>     0
>   \end{bmatrix}
>   +
>   x_2
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     0 \\
>     1 \\
>     \vdots \\
>     0
>   \end{bmatrix}
>   + \dotsb +
>   x_n
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     0 \\
>     0 \\
>     \vdots \\
>     1
>   \end{bmatrix} \\
>   &= x_1 \mathbf{e}_{1} + x_2 \mathbf{e}_{2} + \dotsb + x_n \mathbf{e}_{n} \\
>   &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \mathbf{e}_{i},
> \end{align*}
>   where $\mathbf{e}_{i}$ are the standard basis vectors in $\mathbb R^n$.
>
> Consider the transformation $T(\mathbf x)$.
>   Rewriting $\mathbf x$ as above, we have
>   \begin{align}
>   T(\mathbf x) &= T \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \mathbf{e}_{i} \right) \\
>   &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} T(x_i \mathbf{e}_{i}) \\
>   T(\mathbf x) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i T(\mathbf{e}_{i}). \tag{1}
> \end{align}
>
> Let the matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be defined by
>   \begin{align*}
>   A &=
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     T(\mathbf{e}_{1}) &
>     T(\mathbf{e}_{2}) &
>     \cdots &
>     T(\mathbf{e}_{n}) &
>   \end{bmatrix} \\
>   &=
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
>     \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>     a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}
>   \end{bmatrix},
> \end{align*}
>   where each $T(\mathbf{e}_{i})$ is a column of $A$, and each $a_{ij} = T(\mathbf{e}_{i}) \cdot \mathbf{e}_{j}$ is the $j$th component of $T(\mathbf{e}_{i})$.
>   Then, by the definition of matrix-vector multiplication, we have
>   \begin{align*}
>   A \mathbf x &=
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
>     \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>     a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}
>   \end{bmatrix}
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     x_1 \\
>     \vdots \\
>     x_n
>   \end{bmatrix} \\
>   &=
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     x_1 a_{11} + \dotsb + x_n a_{1n} \\
>     \vdots \\
>     x_1 a_{n1} + \dotsb + x_n a_{nn} \\
>   \end{bmatrix} \\
>   &=
>   x_1
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     a_{11} \\
>     \vdots \\
>     a_{n1}
>   \end{bmatrix}
>   + \dotsb +
>   x_n
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     a_{n1} \\
>     \vdots \\
>     a_{nn}
>   \end{bmatrix} \\
>   &= x_1 T(\mathbf{e}_{1}) + \dotsb + x_n T(\mathbf{e}_{n}) \\
>   A \mathbf x &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i T(\mathbf{e}_{i}). \tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> Therefore, by eqs. (1) and (2), we have that
>   \begin{align*}
>   T(\mathbf x) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i T(\mathbf{e}_{i}) &
>   A \mathbf x &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i T(\mathbf{e}_{i}),
> \end{align*}
>   and we reach $T(\mathbf x) = A \mathbf x$, as was to be shown.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It's the correct proof- very well written.

Comment: The key here is that $e_1,...,e_n$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @copper.hat ah—$\mathbf e_i$ must form a basis so that $\mathbf x$ can be constructed as a linear combination thereof, right? Should I prove that they form a basis? At the risk of jumping to conclusions…isn't it pretty obvious from the definitions of vector addition and scalar multiplication?

Comment: I think it is fairly clear that the $e_k$ form a basis.

Comment: The crux of the proof is that using the standard basis and by linearity, $\mathbf x=\sum\mathbf e_ix_i\implies T(\mathbf x)=\sum T(\mathbf e_i)x_i=\sum\mathbf  a_ix_i$ where the $\mathbf a_i$ can be arranged as the columns of the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is correct as written.

Comment: Further, one can see [the same question in non verification form](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785040/can-any-linear-transformation-be-represented-by-a-matrix).