# Prove each linear transformation can be written as a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'd like to show that Any linear transformation between two finite-dimensional vector spaces can be represented by a matrix. I've seen a proof for linear transformation from and to $\mathbb{R}^n$ but I want to generalize it to any finite-dimensional vector space.

I'd also like to show that the composition of two linear tranformations can be written as a multipication of two matrices. I believe it should look like this:
$$
[S\circ T]^B_D=[S]^C_D\cdot [T]^B_C
$$
Where $T\rightarrow V:W, S\rightarrow U:V$ and $B,C,D$ are bases of $U,V,W$ respectively

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How does one prove those theorems?

Comment: Pick a basis and show that the effect of the transformation on the space is the same as that of the corresponding matrix multiplication. It is sufficient to show this is true for elements of a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the transformation $T$ be from $R^n \to R^m$. We will need bases for each of these spaces, let them be $B_n = \{e_{1n}, e_{2n}... e_{nn}\}$ and $B_m = \{e_{1m}, e_{2m}... e_{mm}\}$ respectively.

Now, any vector $v$ can be expressed as the following

$$v = \sum_1^na_ie_{in}$$

$$\implies T(v) = \sum_i^na_iT(e_{in})$$

To complete the matrix representation, we need to express each $T(e_{in})$ in the basis of the $m$-space

Hence, let $T(e_{in}) = \sum_{k=1}^mb_{ik}e_{km}$

Therefore

$$\implies T(v) = \sum_{i=1}^na_i\sum_{k=1}^mb_{ik}e_{km}$$

Now, we consider the matrix representation of $T$, we express $v$ as a column vector in $R^{n \times 1}$

$$v = \begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2 \\ . \\. \\. \\a_n\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence, $T(v)$ can be thought of as the sum of $m$ vectors in $R^{m \times  1}$, weighted by the $v$ column scalars. Therefore, we pre-multiply by the column wise representation of $T(e_{in})$ in the basis $B_m$, which is given by scalars $b_{ik}$ as defined above

$$[T] = \begin{bmatrix} b_{11} & b_{21} & b_{31} & ... & b_{n1} \\ b_{12} & b_{22} & b_{32} &...& b_{n2} \\ . & .& . \\ .&.&.&.\\b_{1m} & b_{2m} & b_{3m} &...&b_{nm}  \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks, I've seen the proof for $\mathbb{R}^n$ but as I stated, I'd like the proof for the general case.

Comment: proof of what? This is the proof of the general case?

Comment: any transformation $T\rightarrow V:W$ and not just from/to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for some finite-dimensional vector space). Or is this the general proof since each vector space is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yeah, I mean, you could basically replace $R^{n}$ with $V$ and $R^m$ with $W$ in the above proof, I use none of their properties

Comment: Understood, thank you. What about showing the composition of two linear functions is a multipication of two matrices?

Comment: Well, that should follow from writing the final transformation in terms of the basis elements of the final and intermediate spaces, and then showing that the constants can be then expressed as a product of the two matrices

Comment: @snatchysquid I know that this is an old post but in case you still had that question, I think the general case you are referring to is treated in this post. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1785079/145325 As you had rightly guessed, they use the fact that generic vector spaces of dimension $n$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.