# Show or give counterexample: Every subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is the nullspace of some matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show or give counterexample: Every subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is the nullspace of some matrix.

Would it be valid to just state that every subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be described as the null space of some matrix. Is there a counterexample?

I attempted showing the statement true in a concise manner. Does this work?

Let the basis $\{a_1$,$a_2$,$a_3$,$a_4\}$ be subspace S of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Then let some matrix $A= \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1 \\
    a_2 \\
    a_3 \\
    a_4 
  \end{bmatrix}$

The row vectors of A are a basis for the null space of subspace S.

null(S)= A

Comment: If $W\subset \mathbb{R}^4$ is a subspace, take the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}^4/W$ and canonical map between $\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}^4/W$. The nullspace of the linear transformation (and the associated matrix once you choose a basis) is $W$.

Comment: your last sentence makes no sense.  i think you meant to say $Null(S)=R(A^T)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a theorem:

Every Linear Transformation $T: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ has matrix representation. This can be proven just by specifying a basis. A proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916192/proving-any-linear-transformation-can-be-represented-as-a-matrix).

From this, just let $W \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a subspace. From this, consider the natural surjection $\phi: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n/W$, specified by  $x \mapsto x+W$.

The kernel of $\phi$ is exactly $W$, so you take its matrix representation (whatever it may be.)

Answer (score 6):

Let $V$ be a vector space and $U$ a subspace of $V$. Then there is a subsace $W$ such that

$V= U \oplus W$. Define the linear mapping $P:V \to V$ as follows:

for $v \in V$ there are unique $u \in U$ and $w \in W$ such that $v=u+w$; put

$$Pv=w.$$

Then: $ker(P)=U$.

Can you get it from here ?