# How to check $B$ is linear in the proof of Theorem 6.8 in Linear Algebra Done Wrong

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to follow the proof of Theorem 6.8 in *Linear Algebra Done
Wrong*

> Let $A : X → Y$ be a linear transformation. Then $A$ is invertible if
>   and only if for any right side $b ∈ Y$ the equation $$Ax = b$$ has a
>   unique solution $x ∈ X$.

I cannot understand the following part

$B$ is defined as $B:Y \mapsto X$ where $B(y)$ is the unique solution $x \in X$.

[image]

I don't know how to jump from $A(\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2) = \alpha Ax_1 + \beta Ax_2 = \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2$ s to $B(\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2) = \alpha B(y_1) + \beta B(y_2)$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is $B$ defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is the matrix which represents the linear transformation then

$$A(\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2) = \alpha Ax_1 + \beta Ax_2 = \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2 \iff B(\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2) = \alpha B(y_1) + \beta B(y_2)$$

Refer also to the related

- [Proving any linear transformation can be represented as a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916192/proving-any-linear-transformation-can-be-represented-as-a-matrix)

Comment: Yes. I know that a matrix is a linear transformation. And I can also follow the left side of the equation. But the right side, I am not OK.

Comment: @JOHN We are using that $$Ax=y \iff B(x)=y$$ then $$A(\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2) = \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2 \iff B(\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2) = \alpha B(y_1) + \beta B(y_2)$$